# Problems after importing files in Xcode: Autocompletion doesn't work correctly in + how did header path change?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I wanted to organize the Code that I generated so I deleted the references from my project and afterwards created a folder structure in Finder, which organized my classes and the hierarchy.

Afterwards I wanted to add the classes back into my project and selected "create groups for any folders" and deselected "Copy items into destinations group folder (if needed)", because I have multiple projects using the same classes and I wanted to have only one source with one version.

**Now I have the following problem**:
 Editing the classes from within the project, the autocompletion is not working correctly:

The color of variables disappeared (except of the variables like BOOL, float) and the autocompletion for methods doesn't work correctly. It shows only some methods.

Second, I was wondering why all my header imports still work? Where is the compiler looking for when I type #import "test.h"? shouldn't there now also be a folder path included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quitting Xcode and going to the folder:

> /Users/*your_username*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

You should find a folder there whose name begins like your project name.  Delete that folder.

Reopen your project in Xcode and clean then build.

Comment: You can do the same thing from the organizer window in Xcode under the project tab. There is a button to delete the derived data.